# null pointer exception even though photo there

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I realize this question has been asked in various ways, but I couldn't fix my problem despite this.  I'm sure I've done everything correctly and yet it still throws the null pointer exception.  Is this a Windows 7 issue with Eclipse?

I'm attaching a screen shot so you can see exactly how I have things laid out and that it isn't working still.  I really want to trouble shoot this so I can move on in the tutorial I'm doing.  This is so frustrating to be hinged on something so trivial!! My image star.png is located inside the image folder which is in the src folder where the package resides as well.  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Resources (on the classpath) and files (on the filesystem) are two different things.

Comment: You can't get resources by absolute path.

Comment: Can you be more explicit.  I don't understand this well enough to know what you mean.  In all of my classes I've only had to create folders, and then classes.  I've never had to assimilate anything in a different way than that.  Thanks

Comment: You say: "*I'm sure I've done everything correctly and yet it still throws the null pointer exception.*"  Let me assure you that you absolutely definitely have **not** done everything correctly.

Comment: That's a nice assessment.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: Class.getResource: *Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class.* -- The class loader is consulted to find the resource in the classpath.  If you want to find a file in the file system, don't use getResource (but don't expect the file to automatically go along when your app is copied/JARed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To load an image from within an Eclipse project:**

1. Create a new *Source Folder*. Do not use a regular folder like the
   one already in your workspace.
2. Create a new package named "star3.images" in the folder you just created.
3. Copy the images you want (in your case, "star.png") into the package.
4. Load it using the following:

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/star.png"));
```

For all other images, replace "star.png" with the name of whatever image you wish to load.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked!  What is going on exactly with this structure?  I'm sorry--I really want to know how all of this works.  Like I said, I'm so used to just having a couple of class files and an entry point with main.  I don't get the ordering with the packages.  I will follow this schematic though, but I would like to understand :).  Thank you again!

Comment: The new source folder helps organize the project in your workspace. When building the project (Eclipse does this automatically by default), all of the source folders are merged together. By naming the source folder's package using the format "<yourmainpackage>.<subdir>", you are technically placing the files in a subdirectory of the folder with the class files. The method "getClass().getResource(String name)" returns the URL of the file relative to the class file it is called from, and since the files are in a subdirectory, you can get them using the format "<subdir>/<filename>". @NickBlack

Answer (score 0):

**project; properties; java build path; libraries; add class folder**

Add a class folder (called res or something) into the project folder then use:

```
    new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/star.png")).getImage();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by what you mean.  Do you mean create a new folder inside the same project and name it res?  Or is a class folder a particular type of folder?  I don't see anything called res or class folder in my choices through File > New > ...

Comment: Create a new folder in your project folder (I call it res short for resources) and follow the path highlighted bold in eclipse. That sets it up as a class folder which includes it as part of the project, thus allowing you to access it via getClass().getResource.